# Blender 2.8 Grease Pencil disable x-ray

Tags: grease-pencil

How can I disable the X-Ray effect of grease pencil (aka Annotations), so that what I write on a face of a mesh cannot be seen when that face is hidden? Is it possible? 
[image: photo showing annotation on a face disturbing other faces annotations]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same issue until I realized I shouldn't use the Annotation tool but a real grease pencil layer.

*Add > grease pencil > Blank*

You then switch from *Object Mode* to *Draw Mode* and switch the Stroke placement from *Origin* to *Surface*

Comment: Very nice I would not have found it myself... All hidden features, and obsolete things in Blender. I think this way of greasing is useful, while the other way is quite cumbersome, unless you want to have pervasive beacons in your model.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be handled programmatically. Details in this question here: [How to disable x-ray for annotations (grease pencil) in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143090/how-to-disable-x-ray-for-annotations-grease-pencil-in-2-8/165791#165791)